# 4am Shut down of hydro system that uses motor as a generator

Tags: motor, inverter, generator

My micro hydro system "motor as generator" stops generating on random days, but always at 4 am. It seems the resonance between the capacitors and generator winding is lost and the generator goes into hyper rpms triggering the dump loads to engage. It restarts immediately when the dump loads are removed from the circuit.
I have a monitor on the grid power, and the power/voltage is not being lost. There is no other equipment in my building which is in a pretty remote location.
My guess is that the power quality is being disrupted by the local water works (2000 feet away from me), through the starting of large pumps - large motors. A block diagram is attached - does anybody have any ideas ?
Thank you in advance, this is driving me crazy ! Gary

[image]

Comment: Do your inverter indicate any kind of fault?

Comment: Do you log the throughput through the generator?

Comment: The inverter does not indicate any kind of fault - the information in the log is very limited. Thank You

Comment: I do not log what is coming out of the generator - do you have a suggestion how to do so? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your inputs

Comment: I have connected 2 different inverters and the shutdown still occurs at 4 am. I do not get any indication from the inverter as to a fault in the inverter

Comment: The inverter may as well stop feeding the grid because the voltage is temporarily too high. Stop of a large pump?

Comment: Hello Jens - yes that was my thought too. This is a very rural and I checked with the local water works and they state they only have a 5hp pump that runs continuously. The part that has baffled me is why the motor as generator looses excitation and stops generating. Thank you for you inputs !